# Why am I getting ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am using the following code.

```
import pmdarima as pm
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', index_col=0, header=None)

split = int(0.8 * data.shape[0])

train, test = data.iloc[:split], data.iloc[split:]

arima = pm.auto_arima(train, error_action='ignore', trace=1, suppress_warnings=True, seasonal=True, m=12)
```

This gives me a value error

```
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity
```

however when switching the line

```
arima = pm.auto_arima(train, error_action='ignore', trace=1, suppress_warnings=True, seasonal=True, m=12)
```

to

```
arima = pm.auto_arima(data, error_action='ignore', trace=1, suppress_warnings=True, seasonal=True, m=12)
```

I get no errors.

Data is pandas dataframe with two columns one containing dates and the other integers.

data and train both seem to be of the same type so I don't know what is causing this error?

Edit: Full error message with traceback

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/user.a/PycharmProjects/forecastingtrial/example.py", line 17, in <module>
    arima = pm.auto_arima(train, error_action='ignore', trace=1, suppress_warnings=True, seasonal=True, m=12)
  File "C:\Users\user.a\PycharmProjects\forecastingtrial\venv\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\auto.py", line 394, in auto_arima
    **seasonal_test_args)
  File "C:\Users\user.a\PycharmProjects\forecastingtrial\venv\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\utils.py", line 112, in nsdiffs
    dodiff = testfunc(x)
  File "C:\Users\user.a\PycharmProjects\forecastingtrial\venv\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\seasonality.py", line 569, in estimate_seasonal_differencing_term
    stat = self._compute_test_statistic(x)
  File "C:\Users\user.a\PycharmProjects\forecastingtrial\venv\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\seasonality.py", line 509, in _compute_test_statistic
    fit = self._fit_ocsb(x, m, lag_term, maxlag)
  File "C:\Users\user.a\PycharmProjects\forecastingtrial\venv\lib\site-packages\pmdarima\arima\seasonality.py", line 465, in _fit_ocsb
    ar_fit = sm.OLS(y, add_constant(mf)).fit(method='qr')
  File "C:\Users\user.a\PycharmProjects\forecastingtrial\venv\lib\site-packages\statsmodels\tools\tools.py", line 305, in add_constant
    is_nonzero_const = np.ptp(x, axis=0) == 0
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 6, in ptp
  File "C:\Users\user.a\PycharmProjects\forecastingtrial\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\fromnumeric.py", line 2496, in ptp
    return _methods._ptp(a, axis=axis, out=out, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user.a\PycharmProjects\forecastingtrial\venv\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py", line 230, in _ptp
    umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims),
ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: What's the size of `train`?

Comment: @hpaulj it has a shape of (27,1)

Comment: What shape of a `train` input does `pm.auto_arima` expect?  The shape you give is not `zero-size`.  I don't have that module installed.   A full error message (with traceback) might help.

Comment: @hpaulj Hi, apologies for the delay, I have added a full error message at the bottom of my post. I have spent some more time working on this and still can't figure out what is going on, the documentation isn't helping me really (it might be of more use to someone who has more experience) and there isn't really anything much online about this specific module. Would you mind to please take a look when you get a spare moment? Thank you.

Comment: Should `train` have two columns?

Comment: @hpaulj well data has shape `(34,1)` and that runs without error so I don't see why that would be the issue?

Comment: Only you can identify the difference between `data` and `train`.

Comment: I think it is due to the due to the length of train and not being able to detect seasonality of x months thanks for the input anyway.

Comment: I managed to replicate the error and the easiest workaround was to change the ratio of sampling between train and test. In other words, a train sample big enough to accommodate the seasonality parameter (m) should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, the error means that you are trying to get the maximum of an empty array. For example, the code `numpy.amax(numpy.asarray([]))` will throw the error `ValueError: zero-size array to reduction operation maximum which has no identity`. The shape of `numpy.asarray([])` is `(0,)` if you do `numpy.asarray([]).shape` and thus no maximum to retrieve.

Interestingly, `numpy.mean(numpy.asarray([]))` returns `nan` and no error.